# @Observable @Bindable?

Tags: swiftui, xcode15, ios17

Well, iOS17 $ Xcode15 has come along and given us a new way to share data throughout the App by using the @Observable macro set.

I am having so much trouble trying to understand to implement this and make it all work.
I have created a Model file in Swift which I want to share detail across all the views my app will eventually have.

Below shows I have defined the class, which I believe is correct:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Observation
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase


@Observable 
class Authentification {
    
    var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }
    
    func SignIn() {
        print(UserDetail().Email)
    }
    func SignOut() {
        
    }
    func CreateUser() {
        
    }
    func ReturnUser() {
        
    }
    func DeleteAccount() {
        
    }
}

@Observable 
class UserDetail {
    var UserID: String = ""
    var FirstName: String = ""
    var LastName: String = ""
    var Email: String = ""
    var Password: String = ""
    var Location: String = ""
    var Mobile: String = ""
    var Service: String = ""
}
```

My immediate goal is to have a User log-in using Email & Password, using the following View:

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation

struct LogInView: View {
    
    var auth = Authentification()
    @Bindable var user: UserDetail
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            ZStack {
                Image("PlanetEarth")
                    .resizable()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    ScreenTitle()
                    Spacer()
                    
                    TextField("Email Address", text: $user.Email)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                        .opacity(0.8)

                    
                    //Divider()
                    
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: $user.Password)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .opacity(0.8)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)

                 
                    
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            auth.SignIn()
                        }
                    } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Log-In")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                                            }
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, height: 40)
                                            .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                                            .cornerRadius(10.0)
                                            .opacity(0.8)
                    }
```

When I place a: Print(user.Email) above the Button Task 'auth.SignIn()'
I will see in the Debug area the email address print out, so I know this part is doing what it's meant to.

But, when I put the same 'Print' statement in the

```
func SignIn() {
        print(UserDetail().Email)
    }
```

I see nothing, the Email Address is not Binding as I thought it should have done.

Where have I gone wrong?

Pete

Comment: Every time you call UserDetail() you create a different instance one does not know about the other. The inside sign in doesn't seem to be connected to anything

Comment: No @State var ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.    I assumed that the @Bindable macro would do the connection ??

Pitt, where would the '@State var'  fit?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Hi All,   Sorry folks but I am still having problems getting the data to been by other files.      I have uploaded the Swift files up to GitHub if there is anyone willing to point me in the right direction and show me what I am doing wrong.

You will see that there is a LogInView that contain two TextFields .

There is another Swift file (Authertification) which has a func called SignIn.
Inside there is a print statement which when the LogIn Button in the LogInView is pressed, should print the updated Email, but it won't.

Why??

https://github.com/Fritzablez/ServiceME.git